# Nested WebAPI issue with handler mappings (inheritance issue?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, httphandler

I have a Asp.net WebAPI 2 (.net 4.5) site working in isolation on my local machine that I now want to ‘embed’ as a virtual application inside a web forms (.net 4.0) application.

On the server, I have set up a new site and application pool and configured the API there and it works fine. I then created a virtual application within the parent web forms app and pointed it to the same folder location and application pool.

I’ve prevented inheritance of the system.web by wrapping it in a location element

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

Which has fixed some of the issues I was having, but now I’m getting a 500 error. I can see I the event log:

> Exception message: System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule does not
>   implement IHttpHandlerFactory or IHttpHandler.

Which I don’t think is the actual problem but an indicator as to an issue with the handler mappings in the config file. I’ve gone through and added  elements for all the handlers mapped in the parent application, but this hasn’t resolved it.
If I go in the web.config of the API and comment out

```
 <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"
 type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" path="*."
 verb="*" />
```

The error goes away and I get a 200 response but no data back from the API, which makes me think it doesn’t actually know what to do with the request?
I’ve googled about a lot and can’t get to the bottom or this; just wondering if anyone has any suggestions on what this could be?

As I say, in standalone mode the same code/config is working fine – its only when its nested inside another app that’s causing the problem which leads me to think it’s a config inheritance  type issue.

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming that both the Web Forms project, and the WebAPI project each have their own web.config.  Have you tried using the <clear /> attribute in your WebAPI's web.config such that it does not inherit all of the settings of the containing Web Forms web.config?

Comment: if you keep the applications separated,
it would be easier to maintain and evolve.
You could restrict the use of the webapi
to accept only request from your webform app. why the need to embed?

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need to have the WebApi as a virutal application?

It makes more sense to keep it isolated as its own site in IIS.